# jquery change function not working on dropdown

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#title").change(function () {

        var abc = $(this).val();//previously i mentioned this in "" by mistake please update it.
        alert(abc);

    });

});
</script>
```

Datepicker is working fine for me and change function also works fine at [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)


but dont know what went wrong with it in my application.


**Update**:

i think jquery not able to recognize "title" as valid id

Proff: i used onchange javascript function on my DropDownListFor like below

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.title, new[] {
 new SelectListItem { Text = blueddPES.Resources.PES.Resource.mr,Value = "Mr" },
 new SelectListItem { Text =blueddPES.Resources.PES.Resource.mrs,Value = "Mrs"},
 new SelectListItem { Text = blueddPES.Resources.PES.Resource.miss,Value = "Miss"},
 new SelectListItem { Text =blueddPES.Resources.PES.Resource.other,Value = "Other"}
 }, "select", new { onChange = "copyText()" })
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function copyText() {
    var vall = document.getElementById("title").value;
    alert(vall);
    }
</script>
```

Now when dropdownvalue changes then an alert box comes with undefined text;

Answer (score 2):

Replace this line

> $("this").val();

to 
this

```
$(this).val();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot find your element with its Id, you may also try to use

```
 <select onchange="alert(this.value);">
 ...
 </select>
```

or

```
 <select onchange="copyText(this);">
 ...
 </select>


<script type="text/javascript">
   function copyText(that) {

    }
</script>
```

Comment: yup, a smart way to do. Do you have any idea why javascript/jquery not recognizing selected id as valid id.?

Comment: Either element has no Id, or its Id is not "title". Please try to check its Id at runtime using firebug or some other tool.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
$("this").val()
```

Answer (score 0):

just use [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) if elements are created after the page is loaded.

```
$("#title").live('change', function() {

        var abc = $(this).val();
        alert(abc);

    });
```

If you are using JQUERY 1.7 or above then use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: live() function should be used if the DOM structure is changed while loading the control coz the event binding is lost next time the html renders.

Comment: In fact `.live()` is deprecated and should not be used at all.